# How to let wagtail's TimeInput to accept seconds?

Tags: wagtail

I'm using `TimeField` in my model but I'm not able to fill seconds in wagtail's `wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options.ModelAdmin`.
My current `ModelAdmin`s code is:

```
@modeladmin_register
class ScheduleAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = ScheduleCell
    menu_label = _("Schedule") 
    menu_icon = 'date'  
    menu_order = 200  
    add_to_settings_menu = False 
    exclude_from_explorer = False 
    list_display = ('start_time', 'end_time', 'page', 'output_devices')
    search_fields = ('page__title', )
```

current result is

[image]

When I'm trying to write seconds to the input manually - wagtail does not allow it.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date chooser widget doesn't support adding seconds, so you'll need to override this to use a basic text input widget instead. You can do this by adding a `panels` definition to your model (in the next Wagtail release, Wagtail 2.5, it will be possible to define this on the ModelAdmin class too), and specifying the widget there:

```
from django import forms
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel


class ScheduleCell(models.Model):
    # ... field definitions here ...

    panels = [
        # ...
        FieldPanel('start_time', widget=forms.TextInput),
        FieldPanel('end_time', widget=forms.TextInput),
        # ...
    ]
```